# Creating lists of lists (Structs)

Tags: c

I am doing a programming assignment at the moment and I dont really have a full grasp of linking as we havent covered it yet. However I feel I need it to do what I want as arrays are not sufficent

I have created a struct as follows

```
struct node
{
float coef;
int expo;
struct node *link;
};
```

from this I can create pointers to the struct each with different names, however the problem I encountered is that I want user input to determine the amount I structs. I also want the ability to add and create the different structs.

Comment: Ok, that' fine, you just need to keep a pointer to the head struct, then you can find/create the rest at runtime . . . so what's the issue?

Comment: The problem I am having is that the above is a struct for a polynomial. But I cant seem to find a way of creating an undefined amount of polynomials. So the user has the choice of deleting or adding more polynomials at runtime

Comment: So each linked list of structs is a polynomial, and you want a variable number of these linked lists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically resizing an array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346713/dynamically-resizing-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: That's not a dupe, sorry :-(.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I feel if the user wants to delete the 5th element this could become a nightmare to work with. As I would have to move the elements afterward the the deleted one to the correct positions. Am I correct in saying that

Comment: No, you don't need to move anything, you just join the 4th element to the 6th element and deallocate the 5th element, because it's a linked list, not an array.  Ruloff's version shows how to do that for the node structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a head pointer to keep track of your list.

This might be helpful:

```
struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    int count;
};
```

And you need to allocate memory for each new node and move the head to the newly created one.

```
struct node *add_node(struct list *pList, float coef, int expo)
{
    if (pList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct *node pNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    pNode->coef = coef;
    pNode->expo = expo;
    pNode->link = pList->head;

    pList->head = pNode;
    pList->count++;

    return pNode;
}
```

To delete an element you need to move the head forward and then free it previous memory.

```
void *delete_node(struct list *pList, float coef, int expo)
{
    if (pList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    struct node *tmp = pList->head;

    pList->head = pList->head->link;

    free(tmp);

    pList->count--;
}
```

***Note:***

***This is not the ultimate version. I'm just pointing my fingers to what should be done.***

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this as your data structure

```
struct node
{
    float coef;
    int expo;
    struct node *link;
};

struct poly
{
    node *value;
    struct poly *link
}
```

Maintain a linked list of `poly`s, each of which contains a linked list of `node`s.

Comment: This looks to be what im looking for, I will try it.Thank you. If it works I will select this answer.